# PHP Custom 404 Page No Longer working on Chrome Browsers

Tags: php, google-chrome, http-status-code-404

I started getting reports saying that people aren't seeing the custom 404 page our framework uses.

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
header("refresh:0;url=" . ERROR_PAGES_404 );
header("Connection: close");
exit();
```

It just comes up with this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for chrome is that the response needs to be at least 512bytes.  This solved my issue.

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
header("refresh:0;url=" . ERROR_PAGES_404 );
if (preg_match('/WebKit.*Chrome/U', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    echo str_repeat(' ', 550);
}
header("Connection: close");
exit();
```